# Comparing effect of treatment, measured across several time points

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have an experiment in which mice were treated with a drug (or mock treatment) and an enzymatic activity assay was then conducted at four time points, one before the treatment and 3 after the treatment. (The experiment is a bit more complex because I also have different doses of the drug, but here I want to keep it simple).

Here is how my data looks like:

```
> dse_df
# A tibble: 285 x 4
   mouse.id treatment time  activity
   <chr>    <fct>     <fct>    <dbl>
 1 M002     control   T0        7.69
 2 M002     control   T1        8.05
 3 M002     control   T2        7.67
 4 M002     control   T3        8.63
 5 M004     drug      T0        6.47
 6 M004     drug      T1        9.31
 7 M004     drug      T2        9.41
 8 M004     drug      T3        9.09
 9 M006     control   T1        4.91
10 M006     control   T2        5.66
# ... with 275 more rows

> summary(dse_df)
   mouse.id           treatment   time       activity     
 Length:285         control:113   T0:72   Min.   :-1.776  
 Class :character   drug   :172   T1:67   1st Qu.: 5.999  
 Mode  :character                 T2:74   Median : 7.358  
                                  T3:72   Mean   : 7.000  
                                          3rd Qu.: 8.341  
                                          Max.   :11.492
```

If I subtract the value of the assay from the baseline (T0) value, I see a positive effect of the drug relative to the control, and this is consistent across the three time points:

```
> dse_df %>% 
+   spread(time, activity) %>% 
+   gather(time, activity, T1, T2, T3) %>% 
+   mutate(activity_diff = activity - T0) %>% 
+   ggplot(aes(x=time, y=activity_diff, color=treatment))+
+     geom_boxplot()+
+     theme_bw()
Warning message:
Removed 42 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).
```

[image]

However, if I construct a linear model to test the differences between the drug and the control in each time point interdependently, I do not see any statistical significance (see below). Nonetheless, this model does not combine the positive effect from all three time points, and therefore has lower statistical power. How can I construct a model to compare the effect of the drug across all three time points versus the control?

```
> # Construct linear model, with a distinct term for each treatment/time combination
> df_for_lm <- 
+   dse_df %>% 
+   mutate(treat.time = ifelse(time=="T0", "T0", paste0(treatment,".",time))) %>% 
+   mutate(treat.time = fct_relevel(factor(treat.time), "T0") )
> 
> formula_for_lm <- activity ~ 0 + mouse.id + treat.time
> res_lm <- lm(formula_for_lm, data = df_for_lm)
> 
> # Contrats to compare drug vs control at the same time point
> contrasts_mat <- matrix(0, ncol=length(coef(res_lm)), nrow=3)
> contrasts_mat[1, names(coef(res_lm))=="treat.timedrug.T1"] <- 1
> contrasts_mat[1, names(coef(res_lm))=="treat.timecontrol.T1"] <- -1
> contrasts_mat[2, names(coef(res_lm))=="treat.timedrug.T2"] <- 1
> contrasts_mat[2, names(coef(res_lm))=="treat.timecontrol.T2"] <- -1
> contrasts_mat[3, names(coef(res_lm))=="treat.timedrug.T3"] <- 1
> contrasts_mat[3, names(coef(res_lm))=="treat.timecontrol.T3"] <- -1
> colnames(contrasts_mat) <- names(coef(res_lm))
> rownames(contrasts_mat) <- c("drug_vs_control_T1",
+                              "drug_vs_control_T2",
+                              "drug_vs_control_T3")
> 
> res_glht <- multcomp::glht(model=res_lm, linfct = contrasts_mat )
> summary(res_glht)

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = formula_for_lm, data = df_for_lm)

Linear Hypotheses:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
drug_vs_control_T1 == 0   0.3891     0.4521   0.861    0.721
drug_vs_control_T2 == 0   0.4419     0.4291   1.030    0.603
drug_vs_control_T3 == 0   0.8125     0.4315   1.883    0.150
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

- Note - I am using the mouse.id as a fixed effect and not a random effect, because in parallel I am analyzing gene expression data using limma, and I'm not sure if the support for random effect in that context is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I decided to do:

I run a new model `activity ~ 0 + mouse.id + treatment`. This model treats all the time points as if they were replicates of the treatment. Within this model I am testing whether the mean (in some sense) of all treated samples is different than that of the control.

I can say that the drug has an effect on the enzymatic activity if significance was observed in *any* of the time-points, or in the model with all time points combined. However, since these are multiple comparisons, I am adjusting the p-values using FWER (specifically the Hochberg method).